# Spring Boot OAuth 2: Anonymous user after login

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0

I tried to create a OAuth 2 client with Spring Boot 2. But even the simplest official example does not work the way it should because my user doesn't get authenticated and is getting into a login loop.

I cloned the first official Spring Boot OAuth 2 example: https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/master/simple

Its goal is to authenticate a user via an external OAuth authentication server (in the example's case it's Facebook). The only thing I changed was the use of Github instead of Facebook.

After the valid Github authentication and allowing the client to use Github's resources, Github is redirecting back to localhost:8080 with a code and state parameter. But the client is logging:

```
Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
```

After that, a login loop begins: The client software redirects back to Github which redirects back to the client software.

Any ideas why the Spring Boot client software does not authenticate correctly after authentication in Github?

Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SocialApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: (find it in the tutorial)
      clientSecret: (find it in the tutorial)
      accessTokenUri: https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://api.github.com/user

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't solve the problem with Github but I found a working example with my own authentication server: [Simple SSO with OAuth2](https://www.baeldung.com/sso-spring-security-oauth2)

Answer (score 0):

A login loop is probably caused when the service provider at which you are authenticating, is configured with the same redirect URI as you came from.

Instead, you should configure it to redirect to `/login/oauth/code`, as the authorization service will redirect you to that uri with the access token so you can then instead access the resource as authenticated user. (please correct me if I'm wrong in this explanation, I'm still learning to understand how OAuth works)

For more details, check the Protocol Flow in the RFC spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.2